# need help making a looping user input program

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm making a looping user input program and my problem is that it cannot loop, it always end after displaying the statement "Again?" without asking for an user input again.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String yes;
    do{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 10: ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    switch(num){
        
        case 1:
            System.out.print("One");
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.print("Two");
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.print("Three");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Four");
            break;
        case 5: 
            System.out.print("Five");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.print("Six");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.print("Seven");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.print("Eight");
            break;
        case 9: 
            System.out.print("Nine");
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.print("Ten");
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.print ("Invalid Number!");      
            break;
        
    }
    System.out.print("\nAgain? y/n");
    yes = scan.nextLine();
    }while(yes.equals('y'));
    }
}
```

Comment: yes is never going to equal 'y'. yes is a String, 'y' is a char. You also have the issue where the return isn't consumed by your scanner call, so it just looks like the next one can't be executed.

Comment: @Stultuske I tried declaring it as a char but in my while loop displays "char cannot be deferenced"

Comment: you are trying to declare what as a char?

Comment: the "String yes" into "char yes"

Comment: which would make no sense to do. Why would you try that?

Comment: Don't over-complicate things and confuse yourself. You ask the user for input. That user input is a String. Therefor you should just compare that input to a String, and not compare it to a char. so `"y"` is what you should compare it to.

Comment: Move your `Scanner` out of the loop please

Answer (score -1):

try to use scanner.next() instead of nextLine.

And at the loop. You defined 'y'. The single quotes there means that this is a char and not a string. For that reason the loop condition is never 'true'.

See the equal of String

```
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String aString = (String)anObject;
        if (coder() == aString.coder()) {
            return isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.equals(value, aString.value)
                              : StringUTF16.equals(value, aString.value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The given value is not instance of String => false

PS: You should also try not to define the scanner on every loop cycle ;)